# How do I deal with missing values on every row when using caret for prediction?

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a large dataset (200 000+ rows, 140 variables) that has at least one missing value on each row that I have replaced with `NA`. I am trying to use the `caret` library to predict. The `rattle` library can deal with them, but does anyone know how to use `caret`?

The caret library direction says that you should use the below:

```
gbmFit1 <- train(twoplus~., data=training, method='GBM', trControl=fitControl, 
                 na.action=na.omit)
```

but this gives the error:

```
Error in train.formula(twoplus ~ ., data = training, method = "M5", trControl = fitControl,  : 
  Every row has at least one missing value were found
```

Comment: GBM and randomForest algos in H2O can automatically handle NAs.

Answer (score 0):

It simply shows you have some columns which have missing values for all records. Just exclude these columns from your dataset.